# Error while testing route Karma in e2e tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to make some basic end to end tests (e2e) on a django/angularjs application using Karma and I'm getting a weird error.

Here is my test code:

```
# testacular-e2e.conf.js

describe('Log in tests', function() {
   it('should show the disconnected home', function() {
      browser().navigateTo('/#');
      expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/#');
   });
});
```

When I'm running this code, I get the following output:
**[DEPRECATED ERROR - left for reference only]**
<strike>$>karma start testacular-e2e.conf.js
    [2013-04-30 22:19:26.465] [WARN] config - "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
    [2013-04-30 22:19:26.467] [DEBUG] config - autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
    INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://local.host:9876/
    INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
    INFO [PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id cwhp0lnTraNa4ToQ0HkS
    PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac) Log in tests should show the disconnected home FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$document.injector()')
    PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.098 secs / 0.04 secs)</strike>

Any one can help please?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
Here is my Karma configuration file:

```
// Karma configuration

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath = '';

// frameworks to use
frameworks = ['jasmine', 'ng-scenario'];

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  'app/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular-complete/angular-resource.js',
  'app/components/angular-complete/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/components/ng-translate/translate.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/services/services.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];

// list of files to exclude
exclude = [];

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
reporters = ['progress'];

// web server port
port = 9876;

// cli runner port
runnerPort = 9100;


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors = true;


// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel = LOG_DEBUG;


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch = true;


// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers = ['PhantomJS'];

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout = 60000;

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun = false;

// plugins to load
plugins = [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-ng-scenario',
];
```

EDIT 2: Add component.json file

```
# component.json
  {
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.0.5",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.5",
    "angular-resource": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-complete" : "*",
    "jquery" : "~1.9",
    "bootstrap" : "~2.3.1",
    "bootstrap-js" : "*",
    "jquery.localScroll" : "",
    "jquery.scrollTo" : "1.4.4",
    "ng-translate" : ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.0.5",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.0.5"
  }
}
```

EDIT 3 : Updated the above Karma conf file + this is my e2e conf file:

```
// e2e karma configuration

var fs = require('fs');

// Load from basic karma configuration
eval(fs.readFileSync('karma.conf.js')+'');

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  'app/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular-complete/angular-resource.js',
  'app/components/angular-complete/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/components/ng-translate/translate.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/services/services.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];


// Proxy the root path to the location of app server
proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:8000/'
};
```

If you need the details of the files imported in the "files" params, let me know.
With he actual configuration, the "normal" tests (not the e2e ones) works fine but the e2e tests give me the following error:

```
$>karma start karma-e2e.conf.js
[2013-05-01 11:32:19.047] [WARN] config - "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.9.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id HmPYnc9PJUdaGb35pl-K
PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac) Log in tests should show the disconnected home FAILED
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: browser
    at /Users/hugo/Projs/wc/angular/test/e2e/scenarios.js:9
    at /Users/hugo/Projs/wc/angular/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:107
    at http://localhost:9876/karma.js:111
    at http://localhost:9876/context.html:68
PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.082 secs / 0.006 secs)
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your e2e config file:

```
urlRoot = '/_karma_/';
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. If you don't set this when using a proxy for "/" then the karma runner is unable to find the resources it needs to run. Setting urlRoot to a unique URL that's not served by the server under test solves this.

Answer (score 1):

So I was using this exact config ... then I realized that jasmine has no concept of Browser. As soon as I removed jasmine from the frameworks, this error went away.

Of course, I got another one, so off to debug that :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this: If you are using requirejs and bootstrap the page manually, make sure you still have the ng-app directive in your HTML file. This fixed it for me.

`karma 0.9.5`
`requirejs 2.1.6` 
`angularjs 1.0.7`
`karma-ng-scenario 0.0.2`
`karma-chrome-launcher 0.0.2`

Also, this is my config for my e2e tests with the web server running on localhost:8000:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],

        files: [
            'test/e2e/**/*.js'
        ],

        basePath: '../',

        autoWatch: true,

        proxies: {
            '/': 'http://localhost:8000/'
        },

        urlRoot: '__karma__',

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        reporters: ['dots'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-ng-scenario',
            'karma-chrome-launcher'
        ]
    });
};
```

**Edit:** I played around a bit more with my now working configuration to reproduce the error. It occurred again when I did not `sleep()` after navigating to the app root. So this might be worth checking, too.

Comment: I tried this and get several "404 Not Found: /__karma__/app/index.html" from the server and both karma and chrome crash.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of karma are you using? I see a similar error when I run your test:

```
test/e2e/scenarios.js:9:14: TypeError: Object [object Object] 
has no method 'injector'
```

So it's not just your environment. This looks similar to:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1518

which vojtajina suggested addressing by updating karma to get the latest fixes.

As a warning, though, it's worth noting that if you pull karma@canary with npm, you'll have several config changes to make before you can run anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Karma version: 0.8.5
Thanks for your link too. I'll have a look now.

Comment: What config change will I have to make? Do you have any link talking about that?

Comment: I just read your link and tried to update to canary but I have an error saying that testacular is deprecated and that I need to use karma instead... Any suggestion?

Comment: `npm install -g karma@canary` should get you the current version of what was being talked about in that link; the name change from testacular to karma invalidated a lot of old comments. For notes on some of the config changes, see v0.9.0 in the changelog: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Ok after regenerating a clean conf file, it's starting again. 
However, I get the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: browser` when I run the line `browser().navigateTo('/#');` Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at karma's own basic e2e on Git: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/tree/master/test/e2e/angular-scenario - look in the karma.conf.js in particular for things that might be missing from yours. That's my first thought, anyway.

Comment: I just had a look and added the missing stuff but it's still not working... The only main difference compared to your link is that on github, the configurations are now in a module (this has been changed a few days ago). I tried this but I had an error saying that module is undefined...

Comment: Hmm. Update the question with your config/etc as they are now, so we can give them a try?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I really appreciate. I just updated my ticket (EDIT 3)

Comment: Anyone has an idea? I really need to get this fixed... Thanks.

Comment: I had the exact same problem... ended up copying and pasting the exact files from that repo in and slowly modifying them to work with my project. Still not sure what broke it. Karma has terrible, terrible docs.